# Generating SVG files using PHP

Tags: php, html, svg

So, I'm attempting to create some tag images for my users, showing the total points that they have earned. I am attempting to write the SVG in a php file which will add in dynamic content, such as the user's points. I'd like to use a HTML `<img>` tag to fetch the SVG from a file `image_gen.php`.

How would I display the SVG through the `<img>` tag?

Thanks!

Comment: `<img src="/image_gen.php" />`

Comment: This displays a failed resource image. The php file needs a bit of meta data to tell the image tag to process it as an image, not a php file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the following PHP code, I set the content type of the file to `svg+xml`:

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: image/svg+xml');
?>
```